# How to manipulate scroll position after updating gridview row?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Learning asp.net and Web Forms.  I have a very lengthy gridview with an edit button for each row.  Users click edit, it does a postback, then returns with another column now available for edit and the button has changed into an update and delete button.  The problem is when you click edit and the postback occurs, it pops you back up to the top of the page.  How can I get it to back where the user was viewing, or at least back to where the only editable row is visible (preferably in the middle of the view, not the top)?

Comment: Take it from someone who dawdled moving to MVC. If you're just starting the learning process LEARN MVC instead.

Comment: Sounds like you need some ajax. In web forms this commonly implemented with a `<asp:UpdatePanel />` I would research that.

Comment: MVC is on my to-learn list but I work with several older developers and we've got 15 years of applications in ColdFusion, Classic ASP, and WebForms so I have to get a grip on those first.
I did actually try an UpdatePanel but I couldn't get the right combination of things and get them in the right order to where it would even compile. My controls would get errors saying there is no such element when I had them inside the UP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A first step would be to set `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback` to `true` and see if it works as you want. You can set it at the page level:

```
<%@ Page MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" ... %>
```

or at the application level in Web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <pages maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true" ... />
    ...
</system.web>
```

Comment: Does this also work when there are collapsible panels like the one in the AjaxToolkit? I'm just theorizing that if the actual length of the page is variable depending on how many panels are collapsed or not, it would be more difficult to discern scroll position. I would just go try it but those are being used in someone else's app and I'm the new guy and would rather not meddle until I know what I'm talking about.

Comment: I don't know; you can tell us after trying it. For sure, avoiding a complete page refresh would be a cleaner solution. As suggested by zgood, UpdatePanels can be used in ASP.NET WebForms to achieve that. In your case, you would have to put the whole GridView inside the UpdatePanel.